# Correct Encoding style for convert bytes[] to string

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, encoding

I am trying to convert a `byte` array to a string, all i need is to simply convert the number in `byteArray` to string Foreg. `"12459865..."`

I am trying to do this with this:

```
fileInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileInBytes, 0, fileInBytes.Length);
```

`fileInBytes` looks like this: `1212549878563212450045....`
But resultant `fileInString` looks like this `ID3\0\0\0\0JTENC\0\0\0@\0\0WXXX\0...` and alot of weird characters.

I tried different Encoding styles including `default` but all insert some weird characters into it.

The only option I have is to loop and cast each member into the string

```
while (currbyte != -1)
{
    currbyte = fileStream.ReadByte();
    //fileInBytes[i++] = (byte)currbyte;
    fileInString += currbyte.ToString();
    progressBar1.Value = i++;
}
```

But this is `TOO` slow. Please tell me how can I convert by byte array into string using `Encoding.....GetString`

Comment: How do you get your bytes like this `1212549878563212450045`? could you separate it to each byte? such as 12|12|54|98 ... or 1|2||1|2|5|4|9|8...?

Comment: i have updated my question to explain how i made the `fileInBytes` array its basically one like here `fileInBytes[i++] = (byte)currbyte;`

Comment: It's slow maybe partly because of your `progressBar1.Value = i++;`, any UI updating related code will slow everything down, you should update the progressbar in a larger interval of time to reduce this or even in some case we don't even need any exact info on the current process, just some working notification is enough.

Comment: Go with the answer from Tim S. but fileInString += is slow as string is immutable.  If you going down the path should use StringBuilder.  And why would you have a progress bar on an operation that should only take a fraction of a second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to encode a `byte[]` as a `string`, [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) with `Convert`'s [`ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods is a good way to do this:

```
string fileInString = Convert.ToBase64String(fileInBytes);
byte[] asBytesAgain = Convert.FromBase64String(fileInString);
```

Your encoding using `fileInString += currbyte.ToString();` appears to be an ambiguous base 10 encoding. E.g. from what I can tell, the arrays with values `{ 1, 10, 255 }` and `{ 110, 255 }` would be encoded the same: `"110255"`, and so cannot be unambiguously changed back into a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no encoding that can achieve what you want.

You need to loop through the bytes as you do.
To make it faster, use a `StringBuilder` and don't update the ProgressBar too often:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

for (var i = 0; i < fileStream.Length; i++)
{
    builder.Append(fileStream.ReadByte().ToString());

    if (i % 1000 == 0) //update the ProgressBar every 1000 bytes for example
    {
        progressBar.Value = i;
    }
}

var result = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are referring to a byte ARRAY, fileInBytes really can't look like '1212549878563212450045', but rather like this:

```
{byte[22]}
     [0]: 1
     [1]: 2

     etc.
```

If that is indeed the case you should be able fileInString using StringBuilder as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var b in fileInBytes)
{
    sb.Append(b.ToString());
}
fileInString = sb.ToString();
```